# Show pagination only when required

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination, datatables

I'm using [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) that adds pagination at the end of the table. But I want to show the pagination controls only when required, not when there're just a couple of rows. I can't find anywhere to control this.

```
$('#tblSubscriptions').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sServerMethod": "GET",
    "aaSorting": [[0, 'asc']],
    "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url() . 'data/grid/' . $website['WebsiteId']; ?>",        
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "bSortable": false },
        { "bSortable": false },
        { "bSortable": false },
        { "bSortable": false }],
    "bFilter" : false,
    "bInfo" : false,
    "sPaginationType": "two_button"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this in the parameters as well to achieve what you want.

```
"fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
    if ($('#tblSubscriptions tr').length < 11) {
        $('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
    }
}
```